# HLSL Circle all white

Tags: shaders, hlsl

I have been trying to get my shader code (HLSL) to draw a simple circle but after a day and a half I am getting nowhere.  It seems people are using $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$ and remap texcoords but I only get a white quad.

```
    struct VertexShaderStruct
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 Tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexShaderStruct VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderStruct input)
{
    VertexShaderStruct output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
    output.Tex0 = input.Tex0;

    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderStruct input) : COLOR0
{
    float dx = 2 * input.Tex0.x - 1;
    float dy = 2 * input.Tex0.y - 1;
    float hyp = (dx * dx + dy * dy);

    return (hyp == 1)? circleColor : otherColor;
}
```

I define circleColor as blue and otherColor as white, so it seems `hyp==1` always fails.

Comment: I have having this exact same problem. It sounds like your code is now working. Could you post the entire HLSL file contents? It would really help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fragment shader is executed for each fragment with a single uv for this fragment which will probably never fall perfectly on 1.

You could map the target area roughly to the width of a render target fragment.

Eg something like:

```
abs(hyp - 1) * CircleRadiusInPixel < BorderWidthInPixel*0.5
```

**Further explanation:**

Your gpu rasterizes the triangles and executes the fragment shader for each fragment. A fragment is basically a pixel on your screen when MSAA is not active. For each of these fragments the input.Tex0 is filled by interpolating the values from the vertices. As the vertex values for Tex0 range from (0,0) to (1,1) the fragments get values between (0,0) and (1,1). Each fragment only gets one Tex0 representing the value at the center of the current fragment. 
So it is very unlikely that the fragment centers lie EXACTLY at distance 1 from the center of the circle. If you align everything perfectly, you could probably get 4 pixels (left-middle, right-middle, top-center and button-center) to get correctly colored but never the whole circle and it will probably look different on different vga's.

Even if you somehow could be sure that all pixels are aligned, never compare floats you calculated to an exact value. Floats are never exact as they have limited precision and are adjusted to it after each computation. Compare ranges instead.

You can get an even better looking circle adding some kind of fade out:

```
float nonBorder = saturate( abs(hyp - 1) * CircleRadiusInPixel / BorderWidthInPixel*0.5 );
nonBorder = pow( nonBorder, 2.0f );
float4 outColor = lerp( circleColor, otherColor, nonBorder );
return pow( outColor, 1.0f / 2.2f ); // gamma correction
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer has solved my problem.  Id like to understand how you figured out the math or why it works.  Or why mine did not.  I should do some research but at least its solved.  Thanks.

Comment: Anytime, added some additional information!

Comment: You have answered my questions amazingly, and shown me how to improve the circle, which works great. Ive learned most importantly how my calculated floats will most likely not land exactly where I expect and to account for this with ranges.  I will continue to study this until I have it fully cemented.  Thanks a lot for all your help, and I hope others will find this and learn too.

Comment: Kind of a n00b question, but how are you getting `CircleRadiusInPixel` and `BorderWidthInPixel` into your shader function? -- Are they part of your `VertexShaderStruct`?  If so, what are they declared as semantically?

Comment: Figured it out, I was able to pass in the extra information as a `TEXCOORD`.

Comment: You should pass them via shader constants as they do not change during a draw call. Eg [Using Shaders in Direct3D 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509704(v=vs.85).aspx#Initializing_Shader_Constants)